# Solve polynomials equations in $\Bbb Z$

Tags: systems-of-equations, algebraic-number-theory, nonlinear-system

I would like to solve the following system of algebraic equations:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^N {\alpha_i}=0 \\
\sum_{i=1}^N{\alpha_i\beta_i}=0\\
\sum_{i=1}^N{\alpha_i\beta_i^2}=0
$$
where $\alpha_i,\beta_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $N>3$ and $\alpha_i\neq 0\; \forall i$.

---

**Remark:**

- For $N=2$: no non trivial solutions,
- For $N=3$,
  if $\alpha=(\alpha_i)_i$ is non zeros then it is orthogonal to $(1,1,1)$, to $\beta=(\beta_i)_i$ and to $\gamma=(\beta_i^2)_i$.

Therefore $\det((1,1,1),\beta,\gamma)=\prod_{1\le i<j\le N}(\beta_j-\beta_i)=0$

Then for instance $\beta_1=\beta_2=b$ which leads to :

$b=0$ or $\beta_3=b$ or ($\alpha_1=-\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3=0$)
... and the problem seems intricate

- For $N>3$, no idea

Comment: .... ok $\alpha$ is trivial in that case and in the title N is the set of natural numbers

Comment: ... ok ... fine ...

Comment: Since all the $\alpha_i$ are natural numbers which sum to zero, doesn’t that force them all to be zero?

Comment: oups sorry ... it's edited. I put $\Bbb Z$ but since the homogeneity in $\alpha$, we can even allow rational $\alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $N\ge 4$ there exists an additional solution different from the "obvious ones". For this it is enough to consider $N=4$. We obtain the rational solution
\begin{align}
\alpha_1 & =\frac{\alpha_4( - \beta_2\beta_3 + \beta_2\beta_4 + \beta_3\beta_4 - \beta_4^2)}{\beta_1^2 - \beta_1\beta_2 - \beta_1\beta_3 + \beta_2\beta_3}, \\[0.2cm]
\alpha_2 & =\frac{\alpha_4(\beta_1\beta_3 - \beta_1\beta_4 - \beta_3\beta_4 + \beta_4^2)}{\beta_1\beta_2 - \beta_1\beta_3 - \beta_2^2 + \beta_2\beta_3}, \\[0.2cm]
\alpha_3 & = \frac{\alpha_4( - \beta_1\beta_2 + \beta_1\beta_4 + \beta_2\beta_4 - \beta_4^2)}{\beta_1\beta_2 - \beta_1\beta_3 - \beta_2\beta_3 + \beta_3^2},
\end{align} 
with arbitrary $\beta_i$ such that the denominators are nonzero.

A typical "obvious solution" is given by
$$
\alpha_2= - \alpha_3,\; \beta_1=\beta_4, \; \beta_2=\beta_3,\; \alpha_4=-\alpha_1.
$$

Comment: did you use Gröbner basis ?

Comment: but there might be a problem with these formulae: if $\alpha_4$ is free because the terms $\beta_2\beta_4$ don't cancel in the sum of $\alpha_i$

Comment: @Smilia Sorry, I made a copy-paste error with the denominators. They are different. Now it shoud give $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=-\alpha_4$.